# Prevent record creation of an object by selected item in picklist and role

Tags: validation-rule

I have an object called Marketing__c which have a picklist with various items, I need to grant permissions for create and edit this object when in picklist is selected one of two of their items: "Email marketing" or "Mail marketing". All roles can create and edit this object when selecting other items on picklist, but when is one of this two just three roles can do that.

I was trying to create a validation rule for that but without success, every time I try it prevents users with other roles to create any record.

I have just one role here for example.

AND(
CreatedBy.UserRole.Name <> 'Supervisor 3'
) &&
(ISPICKVAL(MarketingOption__c, 'Email marketing')
||
(ISPICKVAL(MarketingOption__c, 'Mail marketing')))

Answer (score 0):

I've reformatted your query so it's a bit more readable:

```
AND( $UserRole.Name <> 'Supervisor 3',
     OR ( ISPICKVAL(MarketingOption__c, 'Email marketing') ,
          ISPICKVAL(MarketingOption__c, 'Mail marketing')
        )
    )
```

I noticed a couple of errors with the logic, which I've fixed ( think )

When you format your code carefully, it's much easier to read and find errors.

If the user is not a `Supervisor 3` and the `Marketing_Option__c` is one of the two provided values - then the the validation rule will fire and edit will be prevented.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and your help. I tried your logic but it let me create/edit records even if my role is differente from "Supervisor 3".

Comment: I'm not sure CreatedBy is actually what you want. I think you just want the current user. Changed to account for that.